# How can I make the legend month-wise instead of alphabetically?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe

```
months  regions frequency
April   Appalachians    4424
August  Appalachians    1435
December    Appalachians    3369
February    Appalachians    2649
January Appalachians    3868
July    Appalachians    1683
June    Appalachians    2290
March   Appalachians    6031
May Appalachians    2421
November    Appalachians    2304
October Appalachians    2184
September   Appalachians    2444
```

And I am plotting using this code

```
ggplot(mcount_appalachian, aes(x=regions, y=frequency, fill=months)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Months",values=bwPalette(12))+
  geom_bar(colour="black",stat="identity", position="dodge")+
  geom_text(aes(ymax=frequency,label = paste(sprintf("%s", frequency)),
                hjust= 0.5,vjust=-1,group=months),
            size = 2, position = position_dodge(width=.9)) +
  facet_wrap(~regions)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour = "black")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL)))
```

This is the figure I am getting. But I would like the legend to be serially month wise (Like Jan, feb...Dec) instead of Alphabetically.

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: This question has been asked and answered _many_ times on SO. Legends and axis annotation follows the level of factor variables. If you are unable to find the answer after searching then please post your search strategy and we will offer another one. If you are able to find the answer then please delete the question.

Comment: I tried several search queries like sort month in R,rearrange month legends in R etc in Google. I didn't know what exactly to search for like "factor levels". But I couldn't find it. Would you mind connecting me to a question?

Comment: For this an SO strategy of `[r] order months ggplot` was pretty effective.

Comment: I used this: mcount_appalachian<-factor(mcount_appalachian$months,
                         levels=c("Jaunary","February","March","April","May","June","July","August",
                                  "September","October","November","December"),
                         ordered=T)

And got this error: Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class orderedfactor

Comment: Don't use 'ordered'. Specifying the levels is sufficient.

Comment: There is also a `month.name` (and `month.abb`) system variable.